# async database call safe

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Hi Im new to MVC and still trying to understand the possible problem of using async.

I have the code below and as you can see i have placed async for all database calls (Not sure whether this is a good practice).
As you might notice this is a simple payment process. I am updating the CustomerPayment entity using the attribute of Customer and also once I added the new transaction, I am updating the balance attribute of the customer.

Using the colde below, will there be any risk of using async in regards to database calls ?

Also, I could see the _context.Database.BeginTransactionAsync() method for transaction, what will be the difference of using BeginTransactionAsync and normal BeginTransaction ?

Any chance this code can be re-written to properly use async ?

```
 using (var dbContextTransaction = _context.Database.BeginTransaction())
            {
                try
                {


                    CustomerPayment cp = vm;
                    Customer c = await _context.Customer.SingleOrDefaultAsync(m => m.CustomerId == vm.SelectedCustomerID);

                    decimal? updatedOutstandingAmount = c.CurrentOutStandingBalance - cp.Payment.PaymentAmount;
                    cp.OutstandingAmount = updatedOutstandingAmount;
                    c.CurrentOutStandingBalance = updatedOutstandingAmount;
                    _context.Add(cp);
                    _context.Update(c);
                    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

                    dbContextTransaction.Commit();

                    TempData["status"] = "CustomerPaymentAdded";
                    return RedirectToAction("Payment", "Customer");
                }
                catch(Exception ex)
                {
                    dbContextTransaction.Rollback();
                }

            };
```

Comment: As long as you're awaiting any asynchronous operations, I don't see what would be the issue.  What makes you think otherwise?  Though there's definitely an issue in that `catch` block, because you're ignoring the exception.  At the very least you should log it somewhere.  Correcting problems is *a lot* easier when you don't ignore the error messages.

Comment: thanks for pointing out the catch block. will put more codes to definitely handle error as i get to the testing phase. what i still don't understand is that if i put what the point is of using async for database calls like above . because database call needs to be called in sequential, will there be any benefit of using async method of entity frameworks ?

Comment: The general benefit to async here is that the top-level application can continue to do other things while low-level operations are executed.  This is why "async all the way down" is important.  The pattern is basically a clean way to expose potentially asynchronous I/O dependencies to the application layer so it can offload those to the host system and continue doing other things.